# Proper size USB wired mouse

Tags: mice

Can anyone suggest a decently sized wired mouse?  Have just tried a Tecknet UM013 but that is 25% shorter than the Microsoft Intellimouse I was intending to replace, just too small to be comfortable.

Comment: You can check this mouse: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B07CM7N7TG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Interesting but unavailable at the moment from Amazon, also can't find any dimensions for it.

Comment: The average dimensions are: 140mm x 70mm x 45mm. And it have special weights to tune the feeling you want. Unfortunately I do not see Amazon to offer something similar now :(

Comment: It is quite similar (maybe rebranded) to this: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Logitech-programmable-computer-customizable-packaging/dp/B07GS6ZS8J/ref=pd_day0_sccl_1_6/258-4823291-1551862?pd_rd_w=OOdYg&content-id=amzn1.sym.a3fbe34d-f78c-44d7-9aa7-253cb614f569&pf_rd_p=a3fbe34d-f78c-44d7-9aa7-253cb614f569&pf_rd_r=ZXZQEASBYQPX93VEQV1Y&pd_rd_wg=xSPG0&pd_rd_r=80139448-fe53-4e18-b0d6-3c834b6e4a86&pd_rd_i=B07GS6ZS8J&th=1

Comment: Ended-up buying one of these in the end, although don't know what it is like until it arrives.

Comment: Oops, forgot the link: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ergonomic-Adjustable-Connection-Illuminated-Backlight/dp/B09M8LTWWK/ref=pd_ci_mcx_mh_mcx_views_0?pd_rd_w=eTitp&content-id=amzn1.sym.6aea875e-359f-49f3-864f-cff62d586b6a%3Aamzn1.symc.ca948091-a64d-450e-86d7-c161ca33337b&pf_rd_p=6aea875e-359f-49f3-864f-cff62d586b6a&pf_rd_r=3XTJEW62SJXSBWDHW5K3&pd_rd_wg=guQyu&pd_rd_r=36b7f483-d599-4e6a-867d-72720197525e&pd_rd_i=B09M8LTWWK

Comment: It may help to improve your question if you include desired size measurements and/or weight.